# Unable to fully remove Juju

Tags: uninstall, juju, init

After downloading Juju and playing around with it a little bit, my curiosity is satisfied. I decided to move on to other endeavors and uninstall Juju, although despite my best efforts a piece of Juju lives on in my syslog (on system boot):

```
kernel: [   16.509086] init: juju-jon-sample-file-storage main process (2163) terminated with status 1
kernel: [   16.509113] init: juju-jon-sample-file-storage main process ended, respawning
kernel: [   16.680103] init: juju-jon-sample-file-storage main process (2164) terminated with status 1
kernel: [   16.680138] init: juju-jon-sample-file-storage main process ended, respawning
kernel: [   16.873943] init: juju-jon-sample-file-storage main process (2165) terminated with status 1
kernel: [   16.873965] init: juju-jon-sample-file-storage respawning too fast, stopped
```

...actual number is much greater, but you get the idea, also present is the identical errors replaced with `juju-jon-sample-machine-agent`.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove juju
sudo apt-get purge juju
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and

```
sudo update-rc.d juju remove
sudo update-rc.d juju-jon-sample-machine-agent remove
sudo update-rc.d juju-jon-sample-file-storage remove
```

Any ideas how to remove my that last piece of Juju stuck to my syslog? I am running 12.04 64 bit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juju installs some upstart files for local provider environments. Prior to removing juju it can be removed via juju destroy-environment for each local environment. Post removal that the upstart files can be removed from /etc/init by hand, their prefixed with the environment name and user name. update-rc.d doesn't work with upstart files afaik.

Answer (score 1):

what you are missing is:

```
stop juju-jon-sample-file-storage
```

This will tell `upstart` to stop respawning the service.
Then, you can safely delete the file `/etc/init/juju-jon-sample-file-storage`.

The other is not respawning, so should not be a problem in your logs or won't be seen dangling in your process list.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These days with the [juju snap](https://snapcraft.io/juju) which is mostly the client the above hints no more apply. To clean any traces of former juju usage for starting fresh you'd do:

```
# Hard reinstall of clients
snap remove --purge  juju
rm -rf ~/.local/share/juju
snap install juju --classic


# Hard re-install of controllers or machines needs a bit more
# Gladly juju leaves a helper to do so
$ sudo /usr/sbin/remove-juju-services
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove juju-core
```