# MythTV in dmesg though it is not installed

Tags: uninstall, init, mythtv

dmesg shows stranges massages. Last year I tried mythtv but it didn't work for me and thus I removed it again.

Today I saw that dmesg shows this messages:

```
[   16.047679] init: mythtv-backend main process (2489) terminated with status 127
[   16.047707] init: mythtv-backend main process ended, respawning
[   16.060100] init: mythtv-backend main process (2503) terminated with status 127
[   16.060124] init: mythtv-backend main process ended, respawning
[   16.071027] init: mythtv-backend main process (2514) terminated with status 127
[   16.071061] init: mythtv-backend respawning too fast, stopped
```

But mythtv is definitely not installed

```
~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mythtv
mythtv-backend                  deinstall
mythtv-common                   deinstall
mythtv-database                 deinstall
mythtv-frontend                 deinstall
mythtv-transcode-utils              deinstall
```

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157093/unable-to-fully-remove-juju) seems to solve a similar problem (with juju instead of mythtv). Obviously the corresponding remedy would be to delete `/etc/init/mythtv-backend.conf`

Can I do so safely? Is there anything else I can/should do (maybe similar to running `stop juju-jon-sample-file-storage` in the previous mentioned post)?

Comment: What's the output of `file /etc/init.d/mythtv-backend /etc/logrotate.d/mythtv-backend && sudo updatedb && locate mythtv`? (The middle part may take a while after you put in your password, that's OK.)

Comment: I can't give that a shot anymore since I already purged everything. Thanks anyway

Comment: That's OK--there's no need to investigate where the files are if you were able to remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dpkg --get-selections` should return nothing for packages that are not installed. The fact that it is returning something is a symptom that there are parts of the package that have not been removed.

If you try `--list` instead of `--get-selections`, you'll see the reason why the package is not fully removed. In your case, you should see `rc` near `mythtv-backend`, meaning that there is still **R**esidual **C**onfiguration for the package.

Files inside `/etc` are considered *configuration files* and are not removed automatically when removing a package. To remove residual configuration, you need to **purge** the package:

```
apt-get purge mythtv-backend
```

This is the correct way of removing all configuration files, including the ones in `/etc/init`.

Comment: Oh Thanks. I only tried `apt-get purge mythtv` which obviously didn't work. No everything is fine. Thanks